# Synchronizing animations across pages

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I am currently building an application that makes use of a simple xaml animation across all pages.

Here is the xaml for the animation

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="raysSpin">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:6.0" To="360" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="sunRays" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

The above animation is on all pages in the app. Now when the user navigates to the next page, I need to keep this animation in sync across all the pages so the it looks like the user hasn't gone onto a different page. The animation, regardless of where it is in the timeline needs to set that position on the new pages animation and begin from where we left off.

Does anyone know or have any ideas on how this can be performed in an efficient way?

My first and only idea was to store the timespan of the animation into a global variable stored in the app.xaml.cs and then in onNativgatedTo of each page, set the new pages animation to the timespan stored and begin from where we left it. It works to a degree, but there is noticeable stutter.

I have thought about running the animation on it's own thread, but I do not know if this is possible and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be for you to split the master page in different parts. One where that controls is kept, and one other where you place the new controls as the user navigates. Even if you have a global variable which you set with the current state of the animations, by the time the new page loads, which unless you have an SLA set, can take a few seconds, the current animation would be already different, if you wanted to give a smooth feeling to the user.

UPDATE:

Something like this:

[image]

You load the new contents into the "New User Controls" pane.

Comment: It is the best way to do it. Have just one page, and use user controls to display the new content. Happy to help :)

Comment: Just a quick question Marco so I get my head around this. Is it possible to keep the navigation stack of the sub pages? The way I interpreted your answer was that you have a master page that my background and animated section and then a section to hold individual pages needed for the app? Kind of like this http://reflectionit.nl/Blog/2013/windows-8-xaml-tips-master-pages